# Datatables hide sort icons on one table, but keep on another

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, pug

So I would like sort icons on all tables, however, they don't fit on one of them as it's pretty crammed anyway and the sort icons make it look ugly. They do fit on other datatables. How can remove the sort icons on just one table only? I tried in the css removing references etc but this seems to effect all of them.

At present, I have in my CSS

```
/* Loading Sorting images for datatables */ 
table.dataTable thead .sorting { background: url('../images/datatables/sort_both.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc { background: url('../images/datatables/sort_asc.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc { background: url('../images/datatables/sort_desc.png') no-repeat center right; }

table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled { background: url('../images/datatables/sort_asc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled { background: url('../images/datatables/sort_desc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right; }


#active-table.dataTable thead .sorting:after
{
    display: none;
   }
}
```

But this doesn't work for hiding the sort icons on table #active-table

Comment: It must work with css. Give that special table a special class, and hide the sort buttons of that special class. If you want us to help you, post some code and what you have tried till now.

Comment: I've added some code so hopefully it's easier to see

Comment: This completely depends on 1) version of dataTable 2) type of UI framework (if any)

Comment: Why are you using: `.sorting:after{display:none;}`?? try: `.sorting{display:none;}`

Comment: Are you trying to disable sorting or simply remove the caret icon and keep sorting functionality? [Ordering](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering) disabled will hide these but stop ordering functionality. Keeping the functionality without visual queues might lead to a confusing UX.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
.dataTable.noOrderIcon > thead > tr > th[class*="sort"]:after,
.dataTable.noOrderIcon > thead > tr > th[class*="sort"]:before{
    content: "" !important;
}
```